# How to access html elements and store them in a json text with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, json

Consider an html form which includes some form elements like labels, select boxes radio buttons etc. With the help of javascript i want to store child elements of that form in a json string like this:

```
{
    "label": {
        "content": "This is a label"
    },

    "textbox",

    },

    "checkbox": {
      "option": "Option 1",
      "option": "Option 2",
      "option": "Option 3"
    },

    "select": {
      "option": "Option 1",
      "option": "Option 2"
}
```

Do you know how can achieve this? Are there any code samples that i can get inspired?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do like following :

```
function setAllElements() {

    var inputElements = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
    var selectElements = document.getElementsByTagName('select');
    var jsonObj = {};


    //Handling of all inputs
    for (i = 0; i < inputElements.length; i++) {
        if (inputElements[i].type == "text")
            jsonObj[inputElements[i].type+i] = inputElements[i].value;
    }

    //Handling of all select
    for (i = 0; i < selectElements.length; i++) {
        jsonObj[selectElements[i].type+i] = selectElements[i].value;
    }

    console.log(jsonObj);

}
```

HTML :

```
<input type="text" value="Text first">
<select id="e">
  <option>A</option>
  <option>B</option>
  <option>C</option>
</select>
<select>
  <option>A</option>
  <option>B</option>
  <option>C</option>
</select>

<input type="button" onclick="setAllElements();" value="Click me!!">
```

If you want JSON Object then key cannot be same ,so i have put like number of the element like if you have 5 `input type="text"` then it will give you text0,text1,text2,text3,text4 with their corresponding values.

```
 {
        text0: "sdfdsf", 
        select-one0: "A", 
        select-one1: "A"
    }
```

Similarly you can extend this function by adding support for all the elements (like textarea, button etc.)that you are using in your page.

Hope it help you !!

Comment: Is there a way to get elements which are a child of form? document.getElementsByTagName is fetching whole document.

Comment: You have not asked regarding the form i your question, in that case you have to get all the forms ,then you can loops through elements of that form, like first elements of form[0], then elements of form[1].

Comment: The first sentence of my problem explanation is starting with form word. Anyway, your suggestion did the job, actually it is a great solution which you have provided. Thank you very much.